# Capture complex type JSON from Request Body in .net core web API controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, apache-kafka, confluent-platform

I have the following in the controller which beautifully captures the `ProducerConfig` Settings coming from QueryString

```
[HttpPost("mylink/load/")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> PostMessageAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken, [FromQuery] ProducerConfig producerConfigs)
```

However, if I decide to change to capture the parameters from the request Body as opposed to QueryString, I am not able to.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> PostMessageAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken, [FromBody] ProducerConfig producerConfigs)
```

I made a request from Postman with following JSON body:

```
{    
    "LingerMs" : 420,
    "BatchNumMessages" : 5,
    "CompressionLevel" : 2,
    "CompressionType" : 1
}
```

and failed with 400 bad request.

**Response**

```
{"type":"https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1","title":"One or more validation errors occurred.","status":400,"traceId":"|246f628d-4624827bfa8633b1.","errors":{"$":["The JSON value could not be converted to Confluent.Kafka.ProducerConfig. Path: $ | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 1."]}}
```

Comment: Hi, @Saher, Have u set PostMessageAsync HttpPost when use [FromBody]?

Comment: It is a Post so I am not sure why it is acting up like that. I ended up using another class and convert the properties to ```ProducerConfig```

Comment: I couldn't see your model of ProducerConfig. From the response, you should check your attribute type or its validation in Confluent.Kafka.ProducerConfig.

Comment: Install Newtonsoft.JSON package to automatically convert.

Answer (score 1):

**Update   23/07**

> {"type":"https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1","title":"One
> or more validation errors
> occurred.","status":400,"traceId":"|246f628d-4624827bfa8633b1.","errors":{"$":["**The**
> **JSON value could not be converted to Confluent.Kafka.ProducerConfig.**
> Path: $ | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 1."]}}

I met this situation before. You could try to install `Newtonsoft.JSON` package.

```
Install Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson package.
```

In your startup.cs add

```
services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson();
```

---

> add `[HttpPost]` if using `[FromBody]`

A `Get` does not send the body of the form, it only requests a `URL`.  Use a `<form>` in your view and post it to your controller method, which needs to be decorated with `HttpPost`.

[image]

> Codes of Controller

```
        [HttpPost("mylink/load/")]
        public IActionResult PostMessageAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken, [FromBody] ProducerConfig producerConfigs) 
        {
            return Json(producerConfigs);
        }
```

> Screenshot of debugging

[image]

> Screenshot  of postman

[image]